# Index Home Page is Blank WP title

Tags: wordpress

The index page for wordpress site is blank. all other pages are fine.

It only show the "site name" for the static home page. Here's an output of the source:

```
<!-- website title -->
<title><?php wp_title( '', true ); ?></title>

> Blockquote
```

Here's a list of the plugins I have installed:

1. All-in-One Event Calendar by Timely
2. amr shortcode any widget
3. Antispam Bee
4. Flexi Pages Widget
5. Google News Keywords from Tags
6. Google Sitemap
7. HTML javscript editor
8. MyGeoPosition.com Geotagging: Geotags / GeoMetatags / GeoFeedtags / GeoMicroformats / Maps
9. Revolution Slider
10. Tint Widget
11. WordPress-to-Lead for Salesforce CRM

Solution:

```
 <title>
 <?php if (is_home () ) { bloginfo(‘name’); }
 elseif (is_category() ) { echo strip_tags(category_description()); }
 elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title().'|'.bloginfo(‘name’); }
 elseif (is_page() ) { single_post_title().'|'.bloginfo(‘name’); }
 else { wp_title(‘’,true); } ?>
 </title>
```

Comment: We're gonna need a little bit more than that. For example - what plugins have you recently installed, what files have you recently changed, did you do an update recently? A little effort goes a long way!

Comment: No recent updates. No files changed.

Comment: Do you have wordpress automatic updates on? What plugins or custom plugins do you have installed. And are you ABSOLUTELY sure no files have changed? Like have you checked?

Comment: WP Engine is installed. All-in-One Event Calendar by Timely, amr shortcode any widget, Antispam Bee, Flexi Pages Widget, Google News Keywords from Tags, Google Sitemap, HTML javscript editor, MyGeoPosition.com Geotagging: Geotags / GeoMetatags / GeoFeedtags / GeoMicroformats / Maps, Revolution Slider, Tint Widget, WordPress-to-Lead for Salesforce CRM

Comment: Look man I'm willing to help but you need to give me more information than "it's not working, fix it". Unless of course you want to pay us to fix it. Please edit your question to include the answers to all of my questions and as much information as possible. Also what have you tried.

Comment: all plugins are up to date. No files other than the header title has been changed. WP title be default does not display page title so looking for workaround....

Comment: OKay that's a bit better, seems like I was a bit quick. I'll edit your question and put that information in it but please do that yourself in future.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all the plugins and switching to the default twenty fourteen theme to see if the issue persists?

Comment: thanks. this is a known issue. I have searched everywhere and can not find a solution thats works. Lots of people propose code but none work. I did doable all plugins. No change

Comment: What about the theme? Did you flip that back to twenty fourteen? Have you modified any of the core files? By known issue, can you please elaborate? C'mon man I'm trying to help you out

Comment: I installed and switched over to twenty fourteen - no change. The only file I have touched is the header file. It's possible someone else may have but I really don't know.

Comment: *still* haven't answered all my questions, did you modify any of the core files and can you elaborate on "known issue"?

Comment: I have not touched anything except the header.  WP title index page blank. Lots of threads online discussing the issue but few seem to work and none have worked for me.

Comment: DO a diff of the files between the latest version from wordpress.org and your files. See what's different - I believe that may show up some changes. When you say you've modified the header, I'm assuming you mean in the template?

Comment: http://kuttler.eu/post/different-titles-for-blog-and-front-page/

Comment: I have simply modified how the title is called, nothing really crazy

Comment: Please don't use the comments to paste in large chunks of code, edit your question and update it with the extra information.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of the plugins and using a stock theme? Open wp-config.php and set debug to true then post the page output with debug enabled.

Comment: all plugins were disabled. No change.

Comment: fixed, see solution above